# Maximum size of a matrix in Fortran 90 avoiding segmentation fault

Tags: matrix, fortran, fortran90

1. What could be the maximum value of N in a NxN matrix in a Fortran 90 code so that no segmentation fault occurs?

   For example, when I use matrices of size 2^8 x 2^8 and using them for multiplications (using intrinsic 'matmul' function), I don't have any problem.

   However, when I used 2^12 x 2^12 matrices, I didn't find any compilation error, but I got segmentation fault in the middle of the program.

   Am I running out the memory allocation or there could be a bug in my code?

   I have used dynamic allocation and I using 64 bit RedHat OS with 64 GB RAM.
2. Also does the maximum size depend on the compiler or the system configuration?

Comment: Just a side-note: with matrices that large you are probably better off using LAPACK routines instead of matmul.

Answer (score 4):

(2) The maximum allocatable size depends on your main memory, and the maximum size of the array constructor (for gfortran) this is 65535 by default and can be set by `-fmax-array-constructor=n`, see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Code-Gen-Options.html).

(1) This is quite easy to calculate:

Double precision complex variables are at 16 Byte. So, if you have an `N x N` matrix and 64GB of RAM, this leads to `N = \sqrt ( 64 GB / 16 B ) \approx 63245`.

So for double precision complex values, you are limited by the main memory.

`Real`s are (typically) at 4 Byte for single precision and 8 Byte for double precision. Single precision complex variables use 8 Byte.

Answer (score 4):

Fortran compilers generally allocate allocatable arrays on the stack; or perhaps on the heap.  Of this I am uncertain, but I am certain that the Fortran standard does not mandate where allocatable arrays are placed.  Your compiler documentation will tell you where, by default, allocatable arrays are placed.  You may find that the fault you are seeing can be avoided by either moving the locus of allocation or by extending the (operating-system determined) stack or heap size.

You could also do yourself a favour by using the `stat` optional argument to any `allocate` statements and catch, in your program, failures to allocate.  You still won't, of course, get an array allocated but this will avoid a program crash.

You should also follow the advice in @Alexander's answer and calculate the size of the arrays you are trying to allocate, fiddling with heap and stack size won't provide you with more space than you have RAM available.

Comment: In my experience, you need to tell `ifort` to allocate arrays on the heap using `-heap-arrays` as soon as large arrays are used. I never had any problems with `gfortran` and large arrays-

Comment: You support one of my points: OP needs to read the documentation for his/her compiler.

Comment: Are you getting allocatable and automatic arrays confused?  It would be a rare beast of a compiler that put allocatable arrays on the stack.  I'm not even sure that it is technically possible to implement them that way (particularly F2003 on).

Comment: @IanH: well, possibly, but it wasn't my intention solely to reveal my ignorance. I intended to be non-committal about the mechanisms that compilers use to implement language features, just like the Fortran standards, and to prod OP into reading the documentation for his/her compiler.  If I assert that allocatable arrays are placed on the stack someone will wander by with a counter-example or a question about what I mean, precisely, by stack.  If you want to rewrite my answer for added accuracy and improved coverage of all bases go right ahead.

Comment: It is entirely possible to implement allocatable arrays on the stack. That's what `alloca(3)` from the standard C library is for (note: not a POSIX call). How good or bad that would be from a technical standpoint is an entirely different story.

Answer (score 2):

You should try setting the stack size to unlimited using

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

I had similar problems, because `ifort` creates large temporary arrays on the stack for matrixoperations and this can lead to unexpected segfaults.

Comment: This is true, but creates a burden on the user of your application (even if that means on you only). I prefer setting `-heap-arrays l` where `l` is some limit size. I use `-heap-arrays 200`. That way arrays larger than 200 kB are placed on the heap.